# Как провести сравнение между массивами чисел и вернуть массив чисел, которые есть только в одном из массивов, но не в обоих

Tags: javascript

```
    //Вот мой пример.


function getDifferences(a, b) {
    let resArr = [];
    
    for(let i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        let curr1 = a[i];
        console.log(curr1);
    }
    for (let j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
        const curr2 = b[j];
        console.log(curr2)
    }
    if (curr1 === curr2) {
        let temp = [curr1, curr2]
    }
    return temp
  }

let resgetDiff = getDifferences([1, 2, 3, 4],[2, 3, 5, 6])
```

Comment: Здравствуйте! Используйте IndexOf.

Comment: мне нужно делать 2 счётчика? что бы в каждом сделать операцию с indexOf?

Comment: Если есть Lodash https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не стоит усложнять, все просто.

```js
function getDifferences(a, b) {
 
    return a.filter(x => !b.includes(x)).concat(b.filter(x => !a.includes(x)));
  }

console.log(getDifferences([1, 2, 3, 4],[2, 3, 5, 6]));
```